# What's the point of liability insurance?

Tags: insurance

My question comes from answers and comments to this question: [Why is net worth a recommended minimum for insurance coverage](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/144858/why-is-net-worth-a-recommended-minimum-for-insurance-coverage)

If a lawyer will bleed you dry (take what you're insured for PLUS what you have in the bank), then why get insurance in the first place?

Similarly, if the lawyer will sue for whatever you're insured for, why bother to get a higher level of coverage?

Comment: In the US, most liability insurance is for automobiles.  You get this insurance because it's a legal requirement.  In a great many cases, the insurance is more than enough to cover damages.  The insurance company often pays without getting lawyers involved, precisely because they'd cost the insurance company money. For example, when my car was rear-ended some years ago, the damage estimate was around $5,000, much less than the policy amount.  The other party's insurance company just wrote me a check.

Comment: Why do you suppose that lawyer cost = insurance + bank account?

Comment: @user253751 did you read the comments and answers in the question I linked?

Comment: @user253751: Observation?

Answer (score 10):

Because **most** insurance claims will be less than the limit of your liability insurance.

A judge isn't going to award a multi-million dollar payout for every minor injury that someone sustained.

Answer (score 7):

Personal liability insurance, aka Umbrella insurance protects your assets from lawsuits (property damage, bodily injury, medical bills, legal fees,  etc.).  There's usually some basic liability in your homeowner's or renter's insurance and you can buy more (it's not expensive).

The opposing lawyer can sue you for any amount that amuses him. But it's presumptuous to assume that a 'lawyer will bleed you dry (take what you're insured for PLUS what you have in the bank)'.  Arbitration or juries determine settlement amounts not lawyers.

Comment: Note again that the possibility of the lawyer taking your insurance coverage + net worth comes from a comment or answer in the linked question.  Was that assertion incorrect?  Do lawyers typically settle at the amount of coverage for serious lawsuits (and does this mean that one might benefit from *less* coverage, which was my other question?)

Comment: Lawyers do not TAKE anything other than a cut of the settlement if they win the case.  A jury determines the size of the settlement based on the severity of the damages incurred.

Comment: Lawyers presumably pressure for higher settlements in order to win a bigger cut (hence take is an accurate verb here IMO).  Is there something I misunderstood about the comments and answers in the question I linked?

Comment: @HorseHair I think what you're missing is that you don't simply get to "name your price" in what compensatory damages you are entitled to. You have to justify your claims by using comparables, receipts or similar.

Comment: @pboss3010 No, I 'm not missing that.  I probably didn't express my question clearly.  My root concern is that (as expressed in the question I linked) in an extreme case a lawyer can drain your insurance plus your entire savings.  The question I linked mentions that some lawyers will first determine your net worth and insurance limits before suing.  Which leads to my real concern: how can one protect themselves when insurance has such limits.  I also pointed out the trend of lawyers suing for more, the greater your coverage.

Comment: You're beating a dead Horse Here.  Nearly half the states have caps on non-economic damages caps.  Some of them also have caps on personal injury, product liability, and medical malpractice.  There is a system out there and what you are missing is that a  lawyer cannot simply drain your insurance plus your entire savings.  Only a jury verdict against you can do so.

Comment: "some lawyers will first determine your net worth and insurance limits before suing" - My auto insurance card instructs me NOT to reveal my insurance limits at the scene of an accident or to another person. As for your net worth, you are right that it is easy to guess - by looking up your domicile on Zillow.

Answer (score 3):

The insurance company will not roll over and pay the entire amount you have insured for. The insurance company will fight to settle for less; and when they settle, it makes your assets protected from the opposing lawyer.

This is why many individuals purchase seemingly-high liability protection from their auto insurer - $300k injury and $100k property, e.g. - this incentivizes the insurer to fight the opposing lawyer. If you buy the minimum liability, your insurer has no incentive to fight - they will write a check for the full amount and leave you to take your chances with the opposing lawyer.

Comment: "Seemingly high"...here in Europe you would struggle to get a liability insurance that has such a low liability limit. The legal minumum for cars is more like tenfold of that

Comment: Florida's liability minimums are $10k injury, $10k property  :D  https://www.flhsmv.gov/insurance/

Comment: $300K as high liability protection?  I've just checked my policy here in the UK.  It has £20 million cover for damage to other people's property, and *unlimited* cover for injury to other people.

Comment: The UK has much valuable historic property, thus the 20 million cover. Florida has stucco buildings, lizards and sinkholes, thus the 10 thousand cover  :D   And, Americans are cowboys or caballeros.

Comment: When I was a 15 year old kid with a Mofa going 25km/h my insurance limit in Germany was DM 2,000,000. That’s one million euros plus many, many years of inflation.